# Postgres: Date grouping in Subquery from timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I am trying find out how many leads are generated per listing per day.

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    vl.listing_id,
    vl.created_at::date as dt,
    (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM voice_leads vl2
        WHERE vl2.listing_id = vl.listing_id 
        AND vl.created_at::date = vl2.created_at::date
    ) as cnt
FROM voice_leads vl
GROUP BY listing_id, vl.created_at::date
ORDER BY listing_id
```

but when executing I get "ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "vl.created_at" from outer query LINE 8: AND vl.created_at::date = vl2.created_at::date"

Any idea on what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to use your alias instead (dt)? Anyway, why do you use a subquery here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    vl.listing_id,
    vl.created_at::date as dt,
    count(cnt.*)
FROM voice_leads vl, lateral (SELECT *
        from voice_leads vl2
        WHERE vl2.listing_id = vl.listing_id 
        AND vl.created_at::date = vl2.created_at::date) cnt
GROUP BY vl.listing_id, vl.created_at::date
ORDER BY listing_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT 
    vl.listing_id,
    vl.created_at::date as dt,
    count( vl.listing_id ) as cnt
FROM voice_leads vl
GROUP BY listing_id, vl.created_at::date
ORDER BY listing_id
```

should do the same.

`count(field)` will count the number of rows in each group.

`count(*)` will count the total number of rows.